# Displaying completely a long string in a Coding4Fun PopUp control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

When I display too long of a string in the `PopUp` control of the [Coding4Fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) Windows Phone toolkit, part of the string goes beyond the border and can not be seen.

[image]

Comment: I did this as a messageprompt, and it seemed to work ok with automatic wrapping of the text.  Can you share some code to show how you're calling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `PopUp` control in the Coding4Fun Toolkit for Windows Phone. `PopUp<T, TResult>` is an abstract class and you should only use it if you plan on implementing custom popups based on it.

Other than that, you have the choice of the following prompts:

- [AboutPrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AboutPrompt&referringTitle=Documentation)
- [InputPrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=InputPrompt&referringTitle=Documentation)
- [MessagePrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessagePrompt&referringTitle=Documentation)
- [PasswordInputPrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toast%20Prompt&referringTitle=Documentation)
- [Toast Prompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toast%20Prompt&referringTitle=Documentation)